# JSON - Rest Interface

Tags: json, rest

I am working with a back end developer who has popped up a REST interface to ship me data in JSON format. **Question 1**: "Should we include some sort of header that states a data format version?". Reason I am asked is that I want to make sure we can control the structure of the JSON data. **Question 2** am I being silly in asking this, the examples I am seeing of JSON don't seem to do this.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: ok, will look at that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common enough request if you need the interface to that REST interface to be stable.

Once that REST API is published, both you and the back-end developer have to figure out what works best for the two of you (and, if there are any, other consumers of that API) when that REST API needs to change in a way that breaks the interface.  If the both of you are able to change at the same time, then great.  There may not be any need for explicit versioning.

However, from your question it sounds like you need the interface for that API to remain stable.  In that case it may benefit the both of you to have some sort of versioning built in.  That way the backend developer can evolve their API without worrying about breaking your app, and you can rely on a stable interface to that API.

In that case, there are (AFAIK) three approaches, one of which is the header you described:

- A version in the Url
- A version in its own request header
- A version in the Accept header

Here's a a blog post (written from the perspective of the back-end developer) that talks through some of those approaches: https://www.troyhunt.com/your-api-versioning-is-wrong-which-is/

Comment: oh good, that helps. I had not thought to put a version in the actual url. I guess we need some method to find the latest version as opposed to one I may currently be using. Thanks for the link, it is good.